# On the definition of a differential equation with an initial value ON the boundary of an open intervall

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

In a textbook that I am reading the author defines a differential equation for values of $t>0$ and an initial condition for $t=0$. As an example consider
$$
y'(t) = 0 \enspace\text{for all } t\in\left]0,\infty\right[, \quad y(0)=1.
$$
I don't fully understand how *solutions* to differential equations are even defined in this case. Clearly, the solution that one thinks of is $y(t)\equiv 1$. But wouldn't the function
$$
y(t)=\begin{cases}1, & \text{if }t=0, \\ 0, & \text{if }t>0 \end{cases}
$$
satisfy this initial value problem, too? After all, it clearly has both required properties, right? In my eyes this kind of solution function should be excluded.

Shouldn't the function and its derivative be defined on the same set? The way I see it the correct way to phrase the initial value problem  (i.e., the way that the author actually had in mind) should be
$$
y'(t) = 0 \enspace\text{for all } t\in\left[0,\infty\right[, \quad y(0)=1.
$$
This would force the solution to be continuous in $t=0$ because $y$ is then necessarily differentiable in $t=0$. The derivative $y'(0)$ is simply, by definition*, the one-sided derivative. And if $y$ isn't continuous in $t=0$, then this one-sided derivative does not exist.

Am I correct? I have not really seen any textbooks that use this notation comment on this issue. Does this mean that for any differential equation on an open intervall one should *demand* that its initial value is given at a point *inside* of this domain? Any input is appreciated.

---

* Many textbooks define differentiablity only for open sets to begin with. Some others (e.g. Rudin) choose the way that I have described above where the one-sided derivative is implemented ad hoc whenever a boundary point is part of the function's domain.

Comment: Does the book not define that an ODE solution has to be continuous (where it is required to exist) and differentiable inside the domain?

Comment: This type of notation is commonly used when dealing with hyperbolic conservation laws. These advanced textbooks don't usually define what a PDE is in all detail.

In all the ODE textbooks that I've checked the initial time always has to be inside of the interval on which the differential equation is given.

Comment: Yes, this kind of setup seems indeed to be geared towards numerical ODE solvers, and "natural" extensions to boundary value problems and PDE.